# Best way to access a logger across an application/website in PHP

Tags: php, logging

I've recently read up on [`PSR-3`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) and am interested in learning about the best way(s) of approaching a logger implementation across a web application or website. I understand how a logger is defined and how they can be implemented per PSR-3, but what about accessing/referencing them across the application for various logging needs such as caught exceptions, notable events, etc.?

These three options came to mind. Are there any more? Which is the best approach?

1. Global object - `$logger->debug('foo')`
2. Global static instance - `Logger::debug('foo')`
3. via some kind of method - `$app->getLogger()->debug('foo')`
4. ...etc...

One of my considerations is keeping the code needed for referencing the logger at a minimum. For example, option 3 above seems like it would get rather tedious to retrieve the logger like that for every appropriate caught exception, notable event, etc., throughout the application.

Comment: What about a *LoggerFactory.getLogger()*?

Comment: In my C# applications, I prefer a static logger. But it contains an instance of a logger which gets set during the configuration of the application, and all calls to the static logger get delegated to that instance. Thus I can replace the actual logger with a simple change in the configuration. I don't know about the concepts used in php, but I guess that this is technically also possible there.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like to use Dependency Injection. Here is some example:

```
class MyClass
{
   public function __constructor(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
   {
       $this->logger = $logger;
   }

   public function someMethod()
   {
      $this->logger->warning('some warning');
   }
}
```

The only thing that you must do is configure the dependency injection container to use your concrete logger class that implements PSR3.

Comment: What about application-wide usage, i.e., looking at the scope of the entire application? Do you use this dependency injection within each and every class you instantiate throughout your application so that there is no external (outside the class) logging?

Comment: I inject the logger in each of the classes that *should* log something. The other classes remain untouched. I don't log all the things that happen in the application, only what I'm interested at some moment.

Comment: Also, when you instantiate `MyClass`, how do you reference the logger in order to pass it into the constructor? Do you use one of the 3 options mentioned in the question, or use a different approach? e.g., `$myClass = new MyClass(<<reference>>);`

Comment: i.e., is it a global reference, static instance, retrieved by some method, etc.

Comment: I use dependency injection so $logger is injected automatically. If you instantiate MyClass manualy from other class, name it MyParentClass, you need to get it injected in MyParentClass class. The dependency injection (DI) is fine if you use it in the entire application; if you don't use DI then you must use a *Service Locator* to find a PSR3 logger like this: `$logger = SomeServiceLocator::singleton()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);`. I see Service Locator as a anti-pattern.

Comment: Anyway, I see your question as being larger: how do you manage your dependencies, generally speaking? You have 3 options: 1.you manage them yourself, using nested `new` calls (OMG!), 2.you use a Service Locator or static method calls (BLEAH!) or 3. you use Dependency Injection (my preferred)

Comment: I agree and favor using DI, I'm just trying to understand how the logger is referenced when it is injected the *first time* it's passed into an object. `MyClass` gets it injected from `MyParentClass`, and that class gets it injected from `MyGrandParentClass`, and so on...but where is the logger originally initialized/stored, so that it is able to be passed into the start of a long line of DI?

Comment: It is instatiated in the composition root of you application

Comment: The DI Container do all the work of resolving dependecies based on the composition root, an early configuration phase of any php script invocation

Comment: Done right Dependency Injection will change your life.

Comment: This is quite late but thank you for sharing your insights!